# g streamer audio error

Tags: linux, gstreamer

I have a g streamer command works well

> gst-launch-0.10 v4l2src  ! videoscale method=0 ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=852,height=480,framerate=(fraction)24/1 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! x264enc pass=pass1 threads=0 bitrate=900 tune=zerolatency ! flvmux name=mux ! rtmpsink location='rtmp://.../live/testing' demux. alsasrc  ! audio/x-raw-int,rate=16000,channels=1,depth=16 ! audioconvert ! audiorate ! audioresample ! *faac bitrate=96000 ! audio/mpeg,mpegversion=4,stream-format=raw ! mux.

but audio samples is decreasing and while streaming some error messages are displayed on the terminal.

> gstbaseaudiosrc.c(840): gst_base_audio_src_create (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAlsaSrc:alsasrc0:
>   Dropped 3520 samples. This is most likely because downstream can't keep up and is consuming samples too slowly.

I tried by reducing the audio sample rates, but that didn't work so help me to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance

Ameeth

Answer (score 0):

Try using Fluendo codec packages

Answer (score 0):

The warning means your CPU is getting overloaded. Why don't you first try with speed-preset=1 or some small value first for x264enc.

Also, add a queue between the capture and encoders so that they can run on different threads.